# Processing language: Get inner array values from ArrayList()

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist, processing

I'm trying to use the ArrayList() method in Processing.

I have this:

```
    ArrayList trackPoints = new ArrayList();

        //inside a loop
        int[] singlePoint = new int[3];

        singlePoint[0] = 5239;
        singlePoint[1] = 42314;
        singlePoint[2] = 1343;
        //inside a loop

    trackPoints.add(singlePoint);
```

So basically I want to add an array "singlePoint" with three values to my ArrayList.

This seems to work fine, because now I can use `println(trackPoints.get(5));` and I get this:

```
[0] = 5239;
[1] = 42314;
[2] = 1343;
```

However how can I get a single value of this array?

`println(trackPoints.get(5)[0]);` doesn't work.

I get the following error:
"The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? How can I get single values from this arrayList with multiple arrays in it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get()` method on ArrayList class returns an Object, unless you use it with generics. So basically when you say `trackPoints.get(5)`, what it returns is an Object.

It's same as,

```
Object obj = list.get(5);
```

So you can't call `obj[0]`.

To do that, you need to type case it first, like this:

```
( (int[]) trackPoints.get(5) )[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `ArrayList` should by typed :

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

If it's not, then you're using a raw List, which can contain anything. Its `get` method thus returns `Object` (which is the root class of all the Java objects), and you must use a cast:

```
int[] point = (int[]) trackPoints.get(5);
println(point[0]);
```

You should read about [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html), and read [the api doc of ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: The last can be abbreviated `println(((int[]) trackPoints.get(5))[0]);`. It saves a line and a temp variable, but the two-line version is a bit easier to read.